# Presence at SDRA/HAMRADIO Friedrichshafen

Tags: discussion

I was just wondering whether people will meet in [Friedrichshafen](https://www.hamradio-friedrichshafen.de/), especially at [SDRA](https://2023.sdra.io/pages/programme.html), considering the community here is at least a bit software-affine, in general.

I'll try to be there (still having to arrange a few things to shuffle that weekend free of obligations), but I thought it might generally be a good idea to have a "raise your hands" here.

Does Ham.SE actually have an "official" presence there, like a booth?

Comment: More generally, it's interesting to ask if ham.SE should or of its members have interest in being a presence at fests to draw attention to this community as a resource.

Comment: I can only speak for myself. I'm not traveling anywhere.